# Trying to understand condensed Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how this code lays out in long format

```
proposed = dict((k, v) for k, v in args.iteritems() if v is not None)
```

The best I can come up with is the following, but it doesn't work:

```
for k,v in args.iteritems():
    print "value of v is: %s" % v
    if v is not None:
    proposed = dict(k,v)
```

However it throws the following error:

TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

Comment: more like `if v is not None: proposed[k] = v`. And setting `proposed = {}` before the loop.

Comment: but you probably want proposed[k] = v and define proposed outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
proposed=dict()
for k,v in args.iteritems():
  print "value of v is: %s" % v
  if v is not None:
    proposed[k] = v #This is the part you got wrong
```

Comment: I have another one: delta = dict(set(proposed.iteritems()).difference(existing.iteritems()))

Comment: @mikey: You should try working that one out for yourself or make a new question. The site has a single question-multiple answer format that makes it easy to find things and prevents (thankfully!) long discussions.